# No admin page for civiCRM on Drupal 8 install (Xampp on Windows 10)

Tags: installation, admin

Sorry if my English contains mistakes.

I just installed Drupal 8 on Xampp (Windows 10 latest version) with Composer and Drush.

I then used the following commands for civiCRM:

*cd /c/xampp/htdocs/site/web/
composer config extra.enable-patching true
composer config minimum-stability dev
composer require civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin:'~1.1'
composer require civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8}:'~5.39'*

I also discovered on the internet that there were various other manipulations to be done:

- change the access rights for ‘civicrm.settings.php’;
- activate the "trusted host" to avoid an error in the administration of Drupal;
- activate the line 'extension = intl' in php.ini; etc.

"cv" being broken from what I could read, I then enabled civiCrm in the extensions and checked user permissions. Everything seems normal, I even tried giving the rights to any authenticated user.

But I am not getting to the civiCRM administration page as you can see.
[image]

I don't have another error message except "You don't have access to any admin page. "
I tried logging out then logging in, but no change.
[image]

I couldn't find anything on the internet that could help me. Am I missing something? A solution, a piece of advice please?

Comment: I don't know about the access denied, but it seems like javascript is not loading. Check the browser dev console for errors, and you might also need to re-run `composer civicrm:publish` which copies the javascript files etc.

Comment: I relaunched the indicated command but unfortunately that does not solve anything.

Comment: CiviCRM doesn't have a page under the Configuration menu - I'm not sure what I'm seeing in that screenshot that suggests otherwise.  As for Javascript not loading, check the Network tab of the Developer Tools for 404 and 500 errors?

Comment: The problem was solved with a fresh install. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I am having the same issue in drupal 9 site and can't seem to get this to resolve

Answer (score 1):

Check the console if any error is showing and make sure your civicrm.settings.php file has correctly set Base URL path (CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL) and $civicrm_paths['civicrm.files']['url'].

In my case it was base path updated wrongly, I have updated and it started working.